# Split 1 row into 2 rows with % of total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table #testdata
(
    ID int,
    Total money
)

insert into #testdata
(
    ID,
    Total
)
select
    1,
    100
union all
select
    2,
    105
union all
select
    3,
    110
union all
select
    4,
    150


select * from #testdata
```

How can I convert each row into 2 rows, the first row having 75% of the total, and the other row being 25% of the total where I can also then include other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `CTE` with the 2 percentages and cross join it to the table:

```
with cte as (select 0.75 val union all select 0.25)
select t.ID, c.val * t.Total result 
from cte c cross join #testdata t
order by t.ID, c.val desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fb6aa8e93a6f992290cae2061be1d128).
Results:

```
> ID |  result
> -: | ---------:
>  1 |  75.00
>  1 |  25.00
>  2 |  78.75
>  2 |  26.25
>  3 |  82.50
>  3 |  27.50
>  4 | 112.50
>  4 |  37.50
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible approach is `VALUES` table value constructor (to get the value and row number for the generated rows) and `CROSS APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM #testdata t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
   (1, t.Total * 0.75), 
   (2, t.Total * 0.25)
) v (ID, Total)
ORDER BY t.ID, v.ID
```

Result:

```
ID  Total       ID  Total
1   100.0000    1   75.000000
1   100.0000    2   25.000000
2   105.0000    1   78.750000
2   105.0000    2   26.250000
3   110.0000    1   82.500000
3   110.0000    2   27.500000
4   150.0000    1   112.50000
4   150.0000    2   37.500000
```

Notes: If you want to eliminate possible rounding issues, use the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM #testdata t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
   (1, t.Total * 0.75), 
   (2, t.Total - t.Total * 0.75)
) v (ID, Total)
ORDER BY t.ID, v.ID
```